# I want to remove "&#160;" from my html in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

Here is what I am getting as a string. I need to put this inside a `<p>` but not able to find any solution

`An investment strategy that's sosimple&#160;and so&#160;effective, we call it the "magic portfolio." It's a way to&#160;guarantee&#160;that you will beat the market.`

I was using

```
return text.replace(/(<[^>]+>)/g, "");
```

Comment: It looks like you want to decode HTML entities. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript/34064434#34064434 work for you? Otherwise, if you just want to remove exactly that. have you tried simply using `return text.replace(/&#160;/g, "");`?

Comment: That's a regular expression that strips tags, not entities.

Comment: is it possible to merge return text.replace(/&#160;/g, ""); with return text.replace(/(<[^>]+>)/g, ""); 

I actually tried with text.replace(/(<[^>]+>)/&#160;/g, ""); and its not working. If I am doing 

text = text.replace(/&#160;/g, ""); 
return text.replace(/(<[^>]+>)/g, ""); working perfectly but If I can merge it will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use text.replcae(your reg expression).replace(your reg expression)